# Floating-point overflow using `train_epochs` in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I am getting the following error (see the stacktrace) when I ran my code in a different GPU (Tesla K-20, cuda 7.5 installed, 6GB memory). Code works fine if I run in GeForce 1080 or Titan X GPU.

**Stacktrace**:

```
File "code/source/main.py", line 68, in <module>
    train.train_epochs(train_batches, dev_batches, args.epochs)
  File "/gpfs/home/g/e/geniiexe/BigRed2/code/source/train.py", line 34, in train_epochs
    losses = self.train(train_batches, dev_batches, (epoch + 1))
  File "/gpfs/home/g/e/geniiexe/BigRed2/code/source/train.py", line 76, in train
    self.optimizer.step()
  File "/gpfs/home/g/e/geniiexe/BigRed2/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/optim/adam.py", line 70, in step
    bias_correction1 = 1 - beta1 ** state['step']
OverflowError: (34, 'Numerical result out of range')
```

So, what can be the reason to get such error in a different GPU (Tesla K-20) while it works fine in GeForce or Titan X GPU? Moreover what the error means? Is it related to memory overflow which I don't think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround that is suggested in `discuss.pytorch.org` is as follows.

Replacing the following lines in `adam.py`:-

```
bias_correction1 = 1 - beta1 ** state['step']
bias_correction2 = 1 - beta2 ** state['step']
```

BY

```
bias_correction1 = 1 - beta1 ** min(state['step'], 1022)
bias_correction2 = 1 - beta2 ** min(state['step'], 1022)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone got here like I did, looking for the same error, but with a CPU using scikit-learn's MLPClassifier, The above fix coincidentally is a good enough hint to fix the sklearn code.

The fix was:
in file .../site-packages/sklearn/neural_network/_stochastic_optimizers.py

change this:

```
self.learning_rate = (self.learning_rate_init *
                      np.sqrt(1 - self.beta_2 ** self.t) /
                      (1 - self.beta_1 ** self.t))
```

to that:

```
orig_self_t = self.t
new_self_t = min(orig_self_t, 1022)
self.learning_rate = (self.learning_rate_init *
                          np.sqrt(1 - self.beta_2 ** new_self_t) /
                          (1 - self.beta_1 ** new_self_t))
```